# Показать правильный пример транслитерации на java

Tags: java, кириллица

необходимо переименовать файлы при скачивании с ресурсов с кириллицы на латиницу. 
На ум приходим вариант использования switch / case, типа:

```
switch (ch){
        case 'А': return "A";
        case 'Б': return "B";
        case 'В': return "V";
        case 'Г': return "G";
        .....
```

но как по мне не очень удачный пример, развернуть простыню на весь алфавит.
может подскажите вариант использования библиотеки, к примеру icu4j или есть что-то получше?

Comment: То же самое, но со словарём.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

добавляем две либы:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**code:**

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator;

public class Transcriptor {

    public static final String CYRILLIC_TO_LATIN = "Cyrillic-Latin";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st = "привет мир";

        Transliterator toLatinTrans = Transliterator.getInstance(CYRILLIC_TO_LATIN);
        String result = toLatinTrans.transliterate(st);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**result:** `privet mir`

Answer (score 12):

Дополню ответ @GoodWin.

Библиотека серьезно обновилась, поэтому в maven добавляем следующую зависимость:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>72.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Инициализируем так:

```
String CYRILLIC_TO_LATIN = "Latin-Russian/BGN"
```

или наоборот:

```
String CYRILLIC_TO_LATIN = "Russian-Latin/BGN"
```

Ну и финальный этап

```
Transliterator toLatinTrans = Transliterator.getInstance(CYRILLIC_TO_LATIN);
String result = toLatinTrans.transliterate(st);
System.out.println(result);
```

Результаты получается гораздо более корректными)

Answer (score 1):

А я дополню ещё. Что если хотите посмотреть все доступные типы транслитерации, то можете это сделать запустив 2 строчки кода:

```
Enumeration<String> availableIDs = Transliterator.getAvailableIDs();
availableIDs.asIterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

И из них себе выбрать необходимый ID для поднятия инстанса транслитератора

А вообще можно сделать вот так и посмотреть что вам подойдёт больше всего

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Привет Мир";

    Enumeration<String> availableIDs = Transliterator.getAvailableIDs();
    availableIDs.asIterator().forEachRemaining(id -> {
        Transliterator toLatinTrans = Transliterator.getInstance(id);
        String result = toLatinTrans.transliterate(input);
        System.out.println(id + " : " +input + " -> " + result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

еще вот так можно (если не хочется добавлять либы в проект):

```
private String transliterateToLatin(String value) {
        return value
                .replace("А", "A")
                .replace("В", "B")
                .replace("Е", "E")
                .replace("К", "K")
                .replace("М", "M")
                .replace("Н", "H")
                .replace("О", "O")
                .replace("Р", "P")
                .replace("С", "C")
                .replace("Т", "T")
                .replace("У", "Y")
                .replace("Х", "X");
    }
```

Comment: Такого типа конвертации в icu4j я как раз и не нашёл. Задача была именно заменять буквы со схожим написанием. Как на номерах авто, если по ошибке их набрали на кириллице.

Answer (score 0):

В одной переменной строка `АБВГД...`, в другой `ABVGD...`
В первой ищете индекс русской буквы, во второй находите по индексу латинский эквивалент.

Comment: с Ж и Ш что делать?

Comment: Что угодно (доп. мини-простыня, массив вместо строки). Я предложил как избавиться от простыни, edge cases это отдельная задача.